# Non-answer by promoter?

Tags: discussion

I had asked for some way to counter aggressive bait and switch advertising by Mobogenie. Their rep (unaware of SE conventions) posted a answer that was less than helpful, promising nothing much. I asked for clarification, which I hope they will provide in a reasonable time, and which I hope will turn into a real answer.

How do I deal with this? Its an answer if Mobogenie promises "no more shady stuff", but I must be skeptical.

[How to prevent MoboGenie popups in Chrome?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/61097/how-to-prevent-mobogenie-popups-in-chrome/86812#86812)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Flagging as spam is correct in this case, IMO. The answer doesn't answer the question, even though it's relevant. It's a half-apology ("we're sorry this happens sometimes, but we're not going to help") combined with an advert ("so would you like to look at some of our products"). I note that this answer has already been removed as spam, so you clearly weren't the only person to think this was the best response. The poster is free to write a new answer if they're going to answer the question this time.

I think there are a few related cases (similar possible answers) that are worth discussing.

> I'm sorry to hear about that. It's not possible to solve that problem with that product alone, but we also sell another product/an upgrade, at http://somecompany.example/products/thethingyouwant

I think an answer like this would pretty clearly be included in our policy that promotional content is OK so long as there is disclosure and it's relevant to the question. In fact, I'd say this is still a good answer, even if the original question was about a competing product from another vendor, so long as the product being recommended solves the problem.

> I'm sorry to hear you've had trouble. Because our awesome product is so flexible, you can solve the problem by ...
>
> By the way, you might like to see our other products at http://somecompany.example/products

Here the promotional content isn't relevant to the question, which is a bit spammy. The rest of the answer is relevant. In a case like this, I think I'd be tempted to just edit out the spammy content, with a helpful edit remark like, "This part of your post isn't relevant to the question. I've removed it to make sure your post isn't removed as spam." **Note** that normally one shouldn't edit out spam links (or other spam content) from posts; it's just that in this case it's probably just a helpful answerer who doesn't understand the community's expectations.

> I'm sorry to hear you've had trouble. Because our awesome product is so flexible, you can solve the problem by ...
>
> --
> John Smith, Somecompany support
> Somecompany: the best Android software ever http://somecompany.example/

In this case, it's pretty clearly just an email signature the support staff thought it would be a good idea to include. We often get people including signatures in posts, and the recommended response is to just edit it out. You can use the edit message to suggest that they include the link & signature content in their user profile. As above, the intent probably wasn't to spam, it's just ignorance of what's expected.

Comment: Very thorough and correct.  I feel like my job is at risk :P

Comment: I didnt flag or otherwise do anything but post this question. IMO deleting is an abrupt thing to do to a person who thought this was a forum, but then Im no expert on moderating busy sites. So lets agree that that answer deserves to be deleted, right?

Comment: @aitchnyu It's not a matter whether it is an abrupt thing or not, but SE is a Q&A site, not a forum; answers should try to solve the problem. Usually, wrong answer will get downvoted but not deleted, but as mentioned in this answer, it's not even trying to solve the case, so it's not an answer (worse, it's a spam). So it's rightly deleted. Your action to post this case on Meta was also appreciated :)